# barplot in R to intuitively visualize income and expenditure

Tags: r, bar-chart

```
year month income expense diff
2016 07 50 15 35
2016 08 30 70 -40
```

I have the data described above, and I want to draw a barplot, income and expense every months in group, left to right, side by side.
For example, in July 2016, it has two vertical bars, between (2016-07,-15) and (2016-07, 35) for income, and between (2016-08, -40) and (2016-08,30) for expense.
I managed to make a graph with R code below, which is different from what I really want.

```
year<- c(2016,2016)
month<-c(07,08)
income<-c(50,30)
expense<-c(15,70)
diff<-c(35,-40)
(dtt<-data.frame(YEAR=year, MONTH=month, INCOME=income, EXPENSE=expense, DIFF=diff))
dttm<-as.matrix(dtt)
barplot(t(dttm[,c(3,4)]), beside=TRUE)
```

[image]

I want to modify this plot like this.Any help will be appreciate.

[image]

Thanks for your attention.
At first I want to add to my previous information, that is, for August 2016 , it has two vertical bars, between (2016-08, 0) and (2016-08, 30) for income, and between (2016-08, -40) and (2016-08,30) for expense.
And I drew a jpeg picture below which was the graph I wanted to draw with R commands.
I hope it makes my presentation easier to be understood.

[image]

Comment: So, which columns you want to print per month and year? This is not clear. Just now you print the `INCOME` & `EXPENSE` column correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
x

month income_expense
1 2016-07             50
2 2016-07            -15
3 2016-08             30
4 2016-08            -75

x$id <- seq_along(x$income_expense)
x$type <- ifelse(x$income_expense > 0, "in",
    "out")
x[x$month %in% c("Starting Cash", "End Cash"),
    "type"] <- "net"
month_type <- paste(x$month, x$type, sep="-")
x.paste<-cbind(x, month_type)

for (i in 1:(length(x.paste)/2)) {
x.paste$start5[2*i-1] <- ifelse(abs(x.paste$income_expense[2*i-1]) > abs(x.paste$income_expense[2*i]) , x.paste$income_expense[2*i],
    0)
x.paste$end5[2*i-1] <- ifelse(abs(x.paste$income_expense[2*i-1]) > abs(x.paste$income_expense[2*i]) , x.paste$income_expense[2*i-1]+x.paste$income_expense[2*i],
    x.paste$income_expense[2*i-1])
x.paste$start5[2*i] <- ifelse(abs(x.paste$income_expense[2*i-1]) > abs(x.paste$income_expense[2*i]) ,x.paste$income_expense[2*i] ,
    x.paste$income_expense[2*i-1]+x.paste$income_expense[2*i])
x.paste$end5[2*i] <- ifelse(abs(x.paste$income_expense[2*i-1]) > abs(x.paste$income_expense[2*i]) , 0,
    x.paste$income_expense[2*i-1])
}

png("Waterfall_bs01.png", width = 500, height = 300, pointsize = 12, bg = "white")
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(x.paste, aes(month_type, fill = type)) + geom_rect(aes(x = month_type,
xmin = id - 0.45, xmax = id + 0.45, ymin = end5,
ymax = start5))

graphics.off()
```

Jimbou

I want to draw expense and income column by month.
In order to do this, I move each vector vertically and then, pass it to geom_rect().
Thanks anyway.